# How to get the CREATE query of an existing materialized view in Hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, materialized-views

I want to extract the entire create query of a materialized view present in Hive. How can I do that? I have the underlying query for data but I want the create query to include storage characteristics, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options -

1. use `describe formatted mv_name` anad then refer to the 'view original text' line for view SQL.
   xx is the name of materialized view
   [image: screenshot]
2. if you are using hue, then you can use table browser to check MV definition/SQL used to create it.

Here is a screenshot on how to get the SQL - xx is the name of materialized view. Create statement below.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW xx AS SELECT * FROM activity;
```

2.1 Click on 'i' and then click on 'Table Browser'.
[image: Screenshot 1]

2.2 Click on 'view sql' to see view query.
[image: Screenshot 2]